# Read file with last col header spanning 2 column values in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a tab delimited file and I wish I to read all col headers but the last 2 columns will have just one column header.

Example 1st row of file:

```
xx  yy  zz  ii  jj
5   5   10  2   a   d
```

In my example, that will be colheader = jj and values will be a and d which spans 2 tabs. I tried with genfromtxt but it gives:

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #2 (got 6 columns instead of 5).
```

I wish I can use numpy's genfromtxt due to my prior code but 
any method will do right now. It seems difficult to use genfromtxt.

I expect a tuple of rows. At one point I got

[(5, 5, 10, 2, b'a') for 1st row but I wish I can get [(5, 5, 10, 2, ['a','d']) if possible

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you expect numpy to do in this case. Numpy arrays are homogeneous, i.e. every element of the array has a single type (there are record arrays which are more complicated). So, what do you expect the array to look like?

Comment: sorry I updated my question with what I expect.

Comment: Where is the value of 2 in your expected output?

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a job for numpy. Your expected output isn't a valid numpy array, unless it's one of dtype=object and that last value is a normal Python list. Pandas might be appropriate, or just an iterable of lists or dicts (using the stdlib `csv` module).

Comment: I am trying pandas now. Still learning pandas so I guess that will help. I just did not want to go modify all I had done previously using numpy genfromtxt